# How to find why /dev/disk isn't created?

Tags: systemd, udev, opensuse, dracut

During boot system logs into journal

```
[    4.604302] x-com (udev-worker)[359]: sda: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules:13 Failed to import properties 'ID_SEAT' from parent: Operation not permitted
[    4.604326] x-com (udev-worker)[359]: sda: Failed to process device, ignoring: Operation not permitted
```

Then I get

```
Warning: dracut-initqueue: timeout, still waiting for following initqueue hooks:
Warning: /lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fdisk\x2fby-uuid\x2f23fe245f-68fa-4619-8411-ba1aa5bbddfa.sh: "if ! grep -q After=remote-fs-pre.target /run/systemd/generator/systemd-cryptsetup@*.service 2>/dev/null; then
    [ -e "/dev/disk/by-uuid/23fe245f-68fa-4619-8411-ba1aa5bbddfa" ]
fi"
Warning: starting timeout scripts
```

And finally it lands in emergency console. I can see there that /dev/disk doesn't exist. Running `udevadm test /dev/sda3` in emergency creates /dev/disk/by-uuid/23fe245f-68fa-4619-8411-ba1aa5bbddfa but it doesn't help to boot system into usable state.
From my understanding this path should be created by udev in 60-persistent-storage.rules or 13-dm-disk.rules. I don't see any related errors before line mentioning 73-seat-late.rules. Here is content of rdsosreport.txt: https://paste.opensuse.org/pastes/b0c8cca5eee2

Why udev don't create /dev/disk path? How can I find what is wrong?

Comment: The first udev-related error in your rdsosreport.txt is: `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:46 Unknown group 'sgx', ignoring`. I don't think `sgx` is a standard group name, so there is a chance this rule file might be corrupted, or relying on corrupted input from somewhere else (hwdb perhaps?). What's on lines 46 and 47 of your `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules`?

Comment: I was ignoring it as unrelated to the real problem but maybe I was wrong. Line 46: `SUBSYSTEM=="misc", KERNEL=="sgx_enclave", GROUP="sgx", MODE="0660"` and Line 47: `SUBSYSTEM=="misc", KERNEL=="sgx_vepc", GROUP="sgx", MODE="0660"` Can it be possible that udev stops interpreting rules from this file at this error? I see that after those lines are lines related to block devices.